# Сoncatenation of rows into one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 columns, one of them is categories:

| Category | AvgSum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 1000 |
| 4 | 10000 |
| 5 | 100000 |

And I need to unite the second and the third row, also the fourth and fifth, and in the received lines perform the operation AVG

So the table has to be like this:

| Category | AvgSum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 550 |
| 3 | 60000 |

Any thoughts?

Comment: you have columns, not rows

Comment: O, yeah, thank you, think about rows all the time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  You can use a `case` expression to define the groups:

```
select (case when category in (2, 3) then 2
             when category in (4, 5) then 3
             else category
        end) as new_category,
       avg(avgsum) as avgsum
from t
group by new_category;
```